# Multiple locks locking the same functions C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I have a simple question about lock.
Are Process1 and Process2 the same because they are eventually locking the LongProcess?
Thank you.

```
private static readonly object _Locker = new object();  
public void Process1()  
{  
    lock(_LockerA){  
        LongProcess()  
    }
}

public void Process2()  
{  
    if(curType == A)
        ProcessTypeA();
    else if(curtype == B)  
        ProcessTypeB();
}

private static readonly object _LockerA = new object();  
public void ProcessTypeA()  
{      
    lock(_LockerA){  
        LongProcess()  
    }
}

private static readonly object _LockerB = new object();  
public void ProcessTypeB()  
{      
    lock(_LockerB){  
        LongProcess()  
    }
}

public void LongProcess()  
{  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same. If you lock against a different object than an already existing lock, then both code paths will be allowed. So, in the case of `Process2` `curtype == 'b'` the lock is using the `_LockerB` object. If one of the other locks using the `_LockerA` object is attempted, then they will be allowed to enter the `LongProcess`.

Comment: So can I say that for process2 different type will be processed concurrently from different instances but within the same type only one will be processed at a time. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer slightly to refer to the lock objects as, well, objects. It has nothing to do with the types, but rather than instances being used against the lock.

Answer (score 0):

`Process1` and `Process2` have the potential to lock the same object, but they are definitely *not* the same. Locks on the same object are however allowed (I think, rarely if ever had to do it) within the same call stack (also referred to as *recursive locking* in the case where `Process1` invokes `Process2`). This could likely be better described as *dependent* locking.

Your question is however fairly vague so you'll have to elaborate on what you mean by *the same*...

Comment: So can I say that for process2 different type will be processed concurrently from different instances but within the same type only one will be processed at a time. Thank you.

Comment: Reviewed your code again. For _Process2_, `ProcessTypeA` and `ProcessTypeB` should be able to run concurrently without incurring the lock.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I just need to make sure that no two TypeA get processed at the same time.